# Foreach loop where clause in Python similar to c# LINQ

Tags: python-2.7

I'm attempting to replicate a c# LINQ foreach statement in python. I'm sure there is a better way.

Let's say I have (in c#):

```
    public class TestData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Something { get; set; }
    }

    void MyMethod()
    {
        List<TestData> myList = new List<TestData>();
        foreach (var i in myList.Where(x => x.Id > 5))
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

I'd like to do something exactly like this in python (2.7). All I need is the foreach loop. Everything else I've got down.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, it's very easy.  The thing with the square braces is called a [List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
for i in [x for x in myList if x.Id > 5]:
    pass #do something
```